# Asp.net Core Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException:

Tags: c#, angular, asp.net-core

i am creating simple crud system in asp.net core mvc with angular i ran into the problem with while updating the records record not updatedd.i got the error as

```
Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.DbUpdateConcurrencyException: 
The database operation was expected to affect 1 row(s), but actually affected 0 row(s);
```

i could save and delete and view the records only i had a problwm with update records.please solve the problem.

**StudentController.cs**

```
     using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using ReactAspCrud.Models;

namespace ReactAspCrud.Controllers
{
    [Route("api/[controller]")]
    [ApiController]
    public class StudentController : ControllerBase
    {
        private readonly StudentDbContext _studentDbContext;


        public StudentController(StudentDbContext studentDbContext)
        {
            _studentDbContext = studentDbContext;
        }

        [HttpGet]
        [Route("GetStudent")]
        public async Task<IEnumerable<Student>> GetStudents()
        {
            return await _studentDbContext.Student.ToListAsync();
        }

        [HttpPost]
        [Route("AddStudent")]
        public async Task<Student> AddStudent(Student objStudent)
        {
            _studentDbContext.Student.Add(objStudent);
            await _studentDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return objStudent;
        }

        [HttpPatch]
        [Route("UpdateStudent/{id}")]
        public async Task<Student> UpdateStudent(Student objStudent)
        {
            _studentDbContext.Entry(objStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(objStudent);
            _studentDbContext.Entry(objStudent).State= EntityState.Modified;
            await _studentDbContext.SaveChangesAsync();
            return objStudent;
        }

        [HttpDelete]
        [Route("DeleteStudent/{id}")]
        public bool DeleteStudent(int id) 
        {
            bool a = false;
            var student = _studentDbContext.Student.Find(id);
            if (student != null)
            {
                a = true;
                _studentDbContext.Entry(student).State= EntityState.Deleted;
                _studentDbContext.SaveChanges();

            }
            else
            {
                a = false;
            }

            return a;



        }

    }

}
```

**Studentcrud.components.ts**

```
  setUpdate(data: any) 
  {
   this.stname = data.stname;
   this.course = data.course;
   

   this.currentStudentID = data.id;
 
  }

  UpdateRecords()
  {
    let bodyData = 
    {
      "stname" : this.stname,
      "course" : this.course,
    };
    
    this.http.patch("https://localhost:7195/api/Student/UpdateStudent"+ "/"+ this.currentStudentID,bodyData).subscribe((resultData: any)=>
    {
        console.log(resultData);
        alert("Student Registered Updateddd")
        this.getAllStudent();
      
    });
  }
```

Comment: What type of database are you using.  You server is a two port application.  One port is the connect from client.  Second port is the connection from server to database.  The error is due to the update command to database failing.  Update MAY be failing because the record doesn't exist in the database and instead you may need to use INSERT.

Answer (score 0):

I think the problem might be that the DBContext does not know which properties changed exactly.

Use the [`Find()`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.find?view=efcore-7.0) method to get the entity, then you can

```
_studentDbContext.Entry(existingObject)..CurrentValues.SetValues(objStudent);
```

Not sure if you can do the same using the [`Attach`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.dbcontext.attach?view=efcore-7.0) method too to save a call to the DB, and (if it works) update all fields whether changed or not.

Comment: i tried not working ...................    i wrote full code of the controller above

Comment: _studentDbContext.Entry(objStudent).CurrentValues.SetValues(objStudent);  if i write it before the    _studentDbContext.Entry(objStudent).State= EntityState.Modified;  this line but not record updateddddd

Comment: No, no. Try to get an existing object first. and pas it to `_studentDbContext.Entry(student)`, like `var student = await _studentDbContext.Students.FindAsync(objStudent.Id); _studentDbContext.Entry(student).CurrentValues.SetValues(objStudent);`